# Angular2 Reactive Form - Form Controls In Other Component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

We have a component which has the form on it (we will call this the booking form), and inside the html form we have inside another component (we will call this the lookup) we do additional logic - and it's in a component as we want to reuse the same functionality again.

The problem is I can't seem to get the formGroupName or formControlName attributes to work in the lookup component.

This is the booking form html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="bookingForm">
    <div class="row">
        <app-lookup [form]="bookingForm"></app-lookup>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the lookup component html

```
<div class="input-field col s12"> 
    <div formGroupName="lookupViewModel">
        <input formControlName="lookupResults{{id}}" id="lookup{{id}}"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The error that appears in the console is

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./LookupComponent class LookupComponent - inline template:1:6 caused by: formGroupName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
      directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the nested `formGroup` to your child component, instead of the "whole" `formGroup`. So the following

```
<app-lookup [form]="bookingForm"></app-lookup>
```

should be:

```
<app-lookup [form]="bookingForm.controls.lookupViewModel"></app-lookup>
```

and in your child view instead of:

```
<div formGroupName="lookupViewModel">
```

it should be a `formGroup`:

```
<div [formGroup]="lookupViewModel">
```

[**Sample plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WGu4LBE3GaX1T0qBQlvG?p=preview)